# mounted method giving error message - Nuxt.js, Jest

Tags: jestjs, nuxt.js

I am new to unit testing and have a question about the mounted method inside the component.

I am testing if the button text is correctly displaying depends on one of the data values, and it passes. However, I have one method in mounted() inside the component and requests API call which is called from nuxt context.

The method is failing and consoling err message from try and catch because looks like it can not find nuxt context inside the test. This is not affecting my test but I wonder if it is fine, or do I need to fix something.

This is my component.

```html
    <template>
        <button>
            {{variations.length > 0 ? 'Select options' : 'add to cart'}}
        </button>
    </template>

    <script>
        data() {
            return {
                variations: [],
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.getVaridations()
        },
        methods: {
            async getVaridations() {         
                try {
                    const variations = await this.$getVatiation.get() // this part is failing and consoling err message from catch
                    this.variations = variations
                } catch (err) {
                    console.log(err) // consoling as TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')
                }        
            },
        },
    </script>
```

This is testing

```js
    describe('Product.vue', () => {
        it('btn display as "Select options" when there is validation', () => {
            const wrapper = mount(Product, {})
            expect(wrapper.find('.product-btn').text()).toBe('Select options') // This passes
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mock any component methods like

```js
import { shallowMount } from "@vue/test-utils";

 describe('Product.vue', () => {
        it('btn display as "Select options" when there is validation', () => {
            const mocks = {
                $getVatiation: {
                  get: () => [] // returns an empty array, change to what you want to return
                }
            }
            const wrapper = shallowMount (Product, {mocks}) // send your mocks as an argument
            expect(wrapper.find('.product-btn').text()).toBe('Select options') 
        })
    })
```

Comment: Hey,  it worked and now it's not showing the error message from catch! Thank you so much :)